# Access model cache in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, caching

Django1.9 cache can be accessed with `from django.core.cache import cache` .
But how can be accessed model cache?

This code worked in previous versions.

```
from django.db.models.loading import cache
from django.db import models


def get_custom_car_model(car_model_definition):
  """ Create a custom (dynamic) model class based on the given definition.
  """
  # What's the name of your app?
  _app_label = 'myapp'

  # you need to come up with a unique table name
  _db_table = 'dynamic_car_%d' % car_model_definition.pk

  # you need to come up with a unique model name (used in model caching)
  _model_name = "DynamicCar%d" % car_model_definition.pk

  # Remove any exist model definition from Django's cache
  try:
    del cache.app_models[_app_label][_model_name.lower()]
  except KeyError:
    pass
...
```

How should I proceed now? I wish to delete model cache

I receive error

```
'LocMemCache' object has no attribute app_models
```

Comment: What isn't working now?

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe a try/except this way you can access cache and keep support for previous version

```
try:
    from django.apps import apps as cache
except ImportError:
    from django.db.models.loading import cache
```